# Ring isomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb Q[x]$ sending $\phi:x\mapsto (y+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The question says:

> "Show that the map $\phi:\Bbb Q[x]\to\Bbb Q[x]$ sending $\phi:x\mapsto (y+1)$ is a ring isomorphism."

$y$ is not defined anywhere. My question is, with superior knowledge of these sort of problems, what was meant to be asked? Alternatively what is being asked if it is written properly and I am just not getting it?

---

I assumed perhaps it was meant to be $x\mapsto x+1$

But as a ring homomorphism we need $\phi(x_1x_2)=\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)$ but $(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\ne (x_1x_2+1)$

So that seems wrong.

Comment: Indeed, it would seem that it should be $x \mapsto x+1$. What you've written doesn't make sense, I'm afraid. You need to show $\phi(f(x)g(x)) = \phi(f(x))\phi(g(x))$ for all $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. For what you've written, you're treating $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ as two different indeterminants which behave the same under your map, which doesn't make much sense; $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a polynomial ring in one indeterminant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a typo, it should be $x\mapsto x+1$, as you said. This **is** an homomorphism:

> if $p(x),q(x)\in \Bbb Q[x]$, then $\phi(p(x)q(x))$ is just the product
>    $pq$ evaluated in $x+1$, which is the same as $p(x+1)q(x+1)$, i.e., $\phi(p(x))\phi(q(x))$. This is essentially the fact that the *evaluation map* is a ring homomorphism (whether you're evaluating elements of the ring or polynomials).

Considering Alex' comment, note you considered $x_1$ and $x_2$ as two different $x$'s, but there is only one indeterminant in $\Bbb Q[x]$, which is $x$, i.e., every element of this ring is a polynomial in **one** variable: $x$.

Comment: In truth I was just using $x_1,x_2$ to denote $f_1,f_2$ but it's true that it was bad notation. But I had $\phi(f_1f_2) = f_1f_2+1$ where we aren't evalutating $f_1f_2$, just adding $1$ to the constant term of the product of the two polynomials. But your answer makes more sense, thanks